# Remodel array of object using reduce

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, reduce

I want to change the structure of the current Array that I am consuming for a better use case, I want to group items into subarrays in this order. soccer > segment name > league > fixtures . I have been stuck on this for hours. I tried to use reduce but none of my attempts was close to success. Below is the sample data and the result I am trying to achieve.

```
 const currentData = [
     {
          "fixtureName": "Fulham vs Chelsea",
          "league": "Premier League",
          "sport": "Soccer",
          "segmentName": "England",
          "markets": []
     },
        {
          "fixtureName": "Arsenal vs liverpool",
           "league": "Premier League",
          "sport": "Soccer",
          "segmentName": "England",
          "markets": []
     },   {
          "fixtureName": "Middlesbrough FC vs. West Bromwich Albion",
          "league": "Championship",
          "sport": "Soccer",
          "segmentName": "England",
          "markets": []
     },   {
        "fixtureName": "Club El Porvenir vs. Berazategui",
        "league": "Primera C",
        "sport": "Soccer",
        "segmentName": "Argentina",
        "markets": []
   },   {
          "fixtureName": "Lille vs Angers ",
          "league": "Ligue 1",
          "sport": "Soccer",
          "segmentName": "France",
          "markets": []
     },   {
          "fixtureName": "PSG vs Nantes",
          "league": "Ligue 1",
          "sport": "Soccer",
          "segmentName": "France",
          "markets": []
     },    {
          "fixtureName": "Argentino de Quilmes vs. Comunicaciones",
          "league": "Primera B",
          "sport": "Soccer",
          "segmentName": "Argentina",
          "markets": []
     
     },   {
          "fixtureName": "Deportivo Merlo vs. Club Atletico Fenix",
          "league": "Primera B",
          "sport": "Soccer",
          "segmentName": "Argentina",
          "markets": []
     },
  ]
```

This is the type of output and result I want

```
const data = [
  {
    sportID: 1,
    sportName: 'Soccer',
    categories: [
      {
        itemName: 'Argentina',
        tournaments: [
          {
            itemID: 1,
            itemName: 'ARG - Primera B',
            events: [
              {
                id: 1,
                itemName: 'Argentino de Quilmes vs. Comunicaciones',
                markets: [],
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                itemName: 'Deportivo Merlo vs. Club Atletico Fenix',
                markets: [],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            itemID: 2,
            itemName: 'ARG - Primera C',
            events: [
              {
                id: 1,
                itemName: 'Club El Porvenir vs. Berazategui',
                markets: [],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        itemName: 'England',
        tournaments: [
          {
            itemID: 1,
            itemName: 'ENG - Premier League',
            events: [
              {
                id: 1,
                itemName: 'Arsenal vs Liverpool',
                markets: [],
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                itemName: 'Fulham vs Chelsea',
                markets: [],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            itemID: 2,
            itemName: 'ENG - Championship',
            events: [
              {
                id: 1,
                itemName: 'Middlesbrough FC vs. West Bromwich Albion',
                markets: [],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        itemName: 'France',
        tournaments: [
          {
            itemID: 1,
            itemName: 'Ligue 1',
            events: [
              {
                id: 1,
                itemName: 'PSG vs Nantes',
                markets: [],
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                itemName: 'Lille vs Angers',
                markets: [],
              },
            ],
          },
         
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected results don't quite match the input, but here's a way to `reduce` each item to its location in the tree, by first creating the tree's objects if not already created.

```js
var currentData = [{"fixtureName":"Fulham vs Chelsea","league":"Premier League","sport":"Soccer","segmentName":"England","markets":[]},{"fixtureName":"Arsenal vs liverpool","league":"Premier League","sport":"Soccer","segmentName":"England","markets":[]},{"fixtureName":"Middlesbrough FC vs. West Bromwich Albion","league":"Championship","sport":"Soccer","segmentName":"England","markets":[]},{"fixtureName":"Club El Porvenir vs. Berazategui","league":"Primera C","sport":"Soccer","segmentName":"Argentina","markets":[]},{"fixtureName":"Lille vs Angers ","league":"Ligue 1","sport":"Soccer","segmentName":"France","markets":[]},{"fixtureName":"PSG vs Nantes","league":"Ligue 1","sport":"Soccer","segmentName":"France","markets":[]},{"fixtureName":"Argentino de Quilmes vs. Comunicaciones","league":"Primera B","sport":"Soccer","segmentName":"Argentina","markets":[]},{"fixtureName":"Deportivo Merlo vs. Club Atletico Fenix","league":"Primera B","sport":"Soccer","segmentName":"Argentina","markets":[]}]


var obj = currentData.reduce(function(agg, item) {
  agg[item.sport] ??= {}
  agg[item.sport][item.segmentName] ??= {}
  agg[item.sport][item.segmentName][item.league] ??= {}
  agg[item.sport][item.segmentName][item.league][item.fixtureName] ??= []
  agg[item.sport][item.segmentName][item.league][item.fixtureName].push(item)

  return agg;
}, {});

console.log(obj)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```